# Interstitial Ads are not displayed after fetching in iOS using Delphi 10.3.3

Tags: ios, delphi, ads, interstitial

I was trying to use AdMob interstitial ads in my app. I was able to implement that in the android version with the guidance and help from various internet sources and self-learning. I am having an issue with the iOS implementation.

With a lot of struggle, I was able to get the "ads" load using the "Mobile Ads SDK" for iOS. My test app compiles and it even fetches the ads. But, when it comes to presenting the ad to the screen, it doesn't seem to work.

I try to display the ad using the following command.

```
procedure TForm8.btnShowAdClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$ifdef android}
  FInterstitial.show;
  {$endif}
  {$ifdef ios}
  if FInterstitial.isReady
  then begin
       ShowMessage ('Showing');
       FInterstitial.presentFromRootViewController
                     (TiOSHelper.SharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController);

  end
  else ShowMessage ('Not Ready');
  {$endif}
end;
```

Nothing happens on this. As per the documentation, the ad should show up right after the call to `presentFromRootViewController`. I am getting the message "Showing" and nothing happens. What I can also see, is my listener for `interstitialWillPresentScreen` is getting invoked; which means it is trying to show the ad and for some reason, it is not.

I tried passing `nil` instead of `TiOSHelper.SharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController` with no success.

I am using Google's test ad unit ID for iOS `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910` for testing. I am 100% sure I am fetching the ad. I confirmed it by checking `FInterstitial.responseInfo.responseIdentifier` every time I fetch the ad. It is not just getting displayed...**Help!!!**

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my own question. I am able to see the Ad once I removed that informational `Showmessage`. It seems it is somehow blocking the view for the Ad. But not sure why!